# How does one find and understand excess data dependencies in a Haskell program

Tags: haskell

How does one find and understand excess data dependencies in a Haskell program so that one is able to eliminate them?

I once used `ghc-vis` to investigate data dependencies in a Haskell program but since Stack has moved on such that `ghc-vis` no longer installs in unison with most current development it's no longer an option and I wonder what do people use these days instead.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a ‘data dependency’? Do you just mean the libraries which `ghc-vis` depends on?

Comment: As I understand it, a data dependency in haskell is where one has to compute something to decide what branch to take in a case expression. They can be the cause of unexpected `_|_` when you make a mistake in your thinking and by a series of dependencies you must compute an expression in order to decide how to compute the expression itself.

Comment: `seq` also adds a data dependency: "seq doesn't evaluate anything just by virtue of existing in the source file, all it does is introduce an artificial data dependency of one value on another" [https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq]

Comment: Thanks @codeshot — I was thinking entirely along the wrong lines! I thought that since `ghc-vis` no longer compiles, you were asking how to fix problems with its dependencies so it does compile. I understand now that you are rather asking how to find data dependencies since the tool you used (`ghc-vis`) now no longer works. That makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: I've edited the wording to improve the clarity. Although a whole-story answer to the question you thought I was asking is also valuable :D

Answer (score -1):

Try to fix ghc-vis (or actually, its dependencies).

From the logs you reported on the ghc-vis issue tracker https://github.com/def-/ghc-vis/issues/24, the errors all belong to these two categories, neither of which requires expertise specific to the broken packages, so you should be able to fix them yourself, that's the beauty of open source:

1. `Failed to load interface... There are files missing`: this might be related to your Haskell distribution. How did you install Haskell? For example Haskell packages on Arch are dynamically linked: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell
2. `Ambiguous occurence`: at least one package you depend on exports a name which clashes with the actually intended name. Look at the broken package and fix its version bounds or fix its imports.

At this point, the problems you are encountering have little to do with ghc-vis, but with wl-pprint-text, polyparse, and cairo.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately nearly everything around Haskell is broken once per year and actually I can't fix it all myself, especially I can't forcibly take over all the relevant servers. Meanwhile, since hardly anyone can be using ghc-vis to find data dependencies the real question still needs an answer.

Comment: Why can't you fix it? And what do servers have to do with this?

Comment: I can't fix it all because there's so much stuff and it gets broken at a rate faster than I could learn it all. Servers are relevant because packages come from the hackage servers, with compatible versions listed in stackage servers. To fix it all I have to change the data on those servers and limit the changes to those servers to prevent new breakage. It sounded like you knew about what it takes to have working open source software - didn't you know?